# jQuery UI multiple autocomplete adding dynamic option to source

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to implement a JQuery autocomplete with specifies options.

Actually my code is the same than the pluging:

```
$( function() {
var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Clojure",
  "COBOL",
  "ColdFusion",
  "Erlang",
  "Fortran",
  "Groovy",
  "Haskell",
  "Java",
  "JavaScript",
  "Lisp",
  "Perl",
  "PHP",
  "Python",
  "Ruby",
  "Scala",
  "Scheme"
];
function split( val ) {
  return val.split( /,\s*/ );
}
function extractLast( term ) {
  return split( term ).pop();
}

$( "#tags" )
  // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
  .on( "keydown", function( event ) {
    if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
        $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  })
  .autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: function( request, response ) {
      // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
      response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
        availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
    },
    focus: function() {
      // prevent value inserted on focus
      return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      var terms = split( this.value );
      // remove the current input
      terms.pop();
      // add the selected item
      terms.push( ui.item.value );
      // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
      terms.push( "" );
      this.value = terms.join( ", " );
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

What I'm trying to do is to add a search function in my autocomplete to have the possibilitie to select a text write by the user (like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kLx7uy7b/) and add the selection in my input.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create multiple autocomplete in an input field based on a sentence structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47531671/how-to-create-multiple-autocomplete-in-an-input-field-based-on-a-sentence-struct)

Comment: Still can't clearly get what you actually want to achieve